# how play Encoded HLS stream in VideoView control or in MediaPlayer of android, Don't want to use other libraries

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, android-video-player

I am using VideoView as my video playing control for hls streaming. I do not want to use other libraries like Vitamio etc. 
I am able to run the simple HLS .m3u8 file from URL, but now I want to play the encoded stream, I have the key, but do not know how to decrypt the encoded stream from url using VideoView or may be MediaPlayer.
Please help me out.
Regards,
Dharma

Comment: if it's AES-128 it should work out of the box

Comment: Yes it's AES-128, but how do i set the key ?

Comment: The key(s) is/are specified in the `m3u8`, you don't need to do anything other than load the URL unless I'm missing something.